# The confusingly indistinguishable nature of a function from its image

Tags: functions

This is something I have taken for granted for so many years and I decided to make it clear.

We encounter the term "sequence" many times, which is a special case of a family, which is a function, which is a special case of a relation, which is a subset of a Cartesian product.

Therefore a sequence should be a set of ordered pairs, where the first and second objects of each pair are a natural number and its corresponding value from the function.

However, we often take a sequence as a set of its image elements by using expressions such as $(x_n) \subseteq \mathbb R$. As the set of real numbers is not a Cartesian product, this confuses and irritates me. Is this just one of those conventional ways of dealing with a function in mathematics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's just a convention. But remember a sequence isn't "really" a set of ordered pairs. It's *formalized* as a sequence of ordered pairs. A sequence is essentially just a countably infinite list of real numbers. That's what a sequence is. But if someone says, "Oh yeah? Let's see you formalize that in set theory!" then you can produce the ordered pair notation.

As another example, what is a real number? In set theory it's a Dedekind cut or an equivalence class of Cauchy sequences. But we'd be excessively pedantic if we insisted on writing every real number that way. Rather, the formalizations are appropriate at one level of discourse, and inappropriate at another.

Comment: Thank you so much for the awesome enlightenment !!!

Comment: You're very welcome!